# how i can use onblur function in cakephp form?

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I have written this validation rule in `Model` but want to validate form data without pressing submit button.

Code:

`public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );`

Do i need to put these rules in function to apply javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without pressing button and for processing you can do this with java script, like

```
<script>
    var input = document.getElementsByName('title')[0];

    input.onfocus = function() {
        (or do anything else what you need)
        this.className = 'some_class_name';
    }

    input.onblur = function() {
        (or do anything else what you need)
         this.className = '';
    }
</script>
```

Or with jQuery or any another library used for project